# Multiprocessor programming: CLH Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

Below is the implementation of CLH Lock from the book The Art of Multiprocessor Programming.

```
public class CLHLock implements Lock {
    private final AtomicReference<QNode> tail;
    private final ThreadLocal<QNode> current;
    private final ThreadLocal<QNode> previous;

    public CLHLock() {
        tail = new AtomicReference<>(new QNode());
        current = ThreadLocal.withInitial(QNode::new);
        previous = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> null);
    }

    @Override
    public void lock() {
        QNode cur = current.get();
        cur.locked = true;
        QNode prev = tail.getAndSet(cur);
        previous.set(prev);
        while (prev.locked) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock() {
        QNode cur = current.get();
        cur.locked = false;
        current.set(previous.get());
    }

    private static class QNode {
        volatile boolean locked = false;
    }
}
```

I replace the ThreadLocal previous field by a volatile field inside QNode to keep track of the predecessor as follows

```
public class CLHLock implements Lock {
    private final AtomicReference<QNode> tail;
    private final ThreadLocal<QNode> current;

    public CLHLock() {
        tail = new AtomicReference<>(new QNode());
        current = ThreadLocal.withInitial(QNode::new);
    }

    @Override
    public void lock() {
        QNode cur = current.get();
        cur.locked = true;
        QNode prev = tail.getAndSet(cur);
        cur.prev = prev;
        while (prev.locked) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock() {
        QNode cur = current.get();
        cur.locked = false;
        current.set(cur.prev);
    }

    private static class QNode {
        volatile boolean locked = false;
        volatile QNode prev = null;
    }
}
```

The first implementation runs fine but the second one deadlocks sometimes. Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with the second implementation? Thank you

Comment: Given that the lock from the book works, why change it?

Comment: There's no need to change it but I just wanted to know why the second one does not work for my learning purpose

Comment: Do you have any ideas so far? Anything that can be tested?